# IDN support in Android

Tags: android, idn

Does Android browser support IDN websites?

Also is this support available for 3rd party applications? In other words can I connect to a webservice hosted on an IDN website from an Android App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can browse IDN domains in Android's browser, but the domain name will be simply converted to the Punycode notation, so you will see `www.xn--br-via.com` instead of `www.bär.com` in the adress bar.

If you want to access such domains, you have to convert the domain to Punycode.

You can do this programmatically with [java.net.IDN](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/IDN.html), or you could use [an online converter](http://idnaconv.phlymail.de/) and work with the Punycode notation.